# How can I define a type that represents the subclass of an abstract class with static methods?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How can I define a type that is the subclass of another class (including the static methods on the parent class)?

#### Simplified Example

Let's say I have two abstract base classes and two concrete subclasses (one for each):

```js
abstract class BaseEntity {
  foo?: string;

  static init<T extends BaseEntity>(this: new () => T, data: Partial<T>): T {
    return Object.assign(new this(), data);
  }
}

class FooBarEntity extends BaseEntity {
  bar?: string;
}

abstract class BasePrinter<T extends BaseEntity> {

  constructor(
    private entityClass: typeof BaseEntity   // <-- This would work if BaseEntity weren't abstract.
                                             //     What should I do instead of this?
  ) {}
  
  initAndPrint(data: Partial<T>) {
    const entity = this.entityClass.init(data);

    console.log(entity);
  }
}

class FooBarPrinter extends BasePrinter<FooBarEntity> {
  // ...
}
```

#### Goal

I want to be able to do this:

```js
const myPrinter = new FooBarPrinter(FooBarEntity);

myPrinter.initAndPrint({ foo: 'FOO', bar: 'BAR' });    // FooBarEntity { foo: 'FOO', bar: 'BAR' }
```

I could just define a type that contains a function called `initAndPrint` but I'm hoping to figure out a more generic/universal approach if I can.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try it with a generic type `BaseEntityConstructor` to represent the static part? (See for example this [blog post](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/15573960.html))

If you define

```
interface BaseEntityConstructor<T extends BaseEntity> {
  new (): T;

  init(this: new () => T, data: Partial<T>): T
}
```

and replace `typeof BaseEntity` in the `BasePrinter` constructor with `BaseEntityConstructor<T>`:

```
abstract class BasePrinter<T extends BaseEntity> {
  constructor(
    private entityClass: BaseEntityConstructor<T>
  ) {}
  ..
}
```

the example type checks and runs okay.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgUQDsIBLCATwQG8AoBBAMwHtGB+ALgUimIIHMBuarU4RgJWAh6kAPABUEOAB4QcBACYZsYfEVJkAfAAoIAC2JgOBHAHcEhgJQIAvPoSyANAjVjgHAArAUCTAyHL69hzyNHR0UDgQAK5QBAgA8iAAVjjwAHRoYMS8BIZWtqbmDp7eovaCdAC+1I3UPCpQ9HA4WLiEJOQAwowEXAnwjFByCsqqGt3avXqu0QildhFugsJSEMZmFis2a86uHl4+-oHBobLhkU1CKPkIAGLM2FAL5FMq6po9ul9liBAuwRNw+IJmqAuHBEI90HMcH5wW1JkofrMtDo+gYqMJYEMRmMoIZhHQAA7cABuYi6qhx-VQ6A4WM+ZEGw2gowg4zCwkclEadC2BFIAEF1MjWoZqr4EAEgsQQmEBWSkITEPS9M4EOUwDktQMmfrtjKfLUhDF1cNGMgcDlkIxeIZDWQLQ17tR4RhXox3lKiDgoN8Zn9tAHUb73mylsIAPRxhA5ZOehMIADijBCDw1CAAtmQI0Gdaso4EiySyx8AW7NgWKzlthK1BHDJQGMwOAByZ6pVJdzzAqDdzBigBKXYQ9VqCDTVbZVA7jG7vf7g8CI-Hk8aQA)

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up coming up with this:

```
type ConstructorType<T = any> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

type BaseEntityType<T> = ConstructorType<T> & {
  [K in keyof typeof BaseEntity]: (typeof BaseEntity)[K]
}
```

Which basically defines a generic constructor function type `ConstructorType<T>` and then defines a combination of it with the static properties on BaseEntity to create a type that seems to work the way I expected.

Not sure if there are any egde cases or something I didn't account for, but so far it seems to work.